# Alfresco, access the server from local network

Tags: ip, alfresco

I'm trying to work Alfresco. It was installed on the local server. Tomcat is a webserver that is used by Alfresco to provide an access to the web-panel. Default ip is: 127.0.0.1:8080; 
And now I want to get an access form another local computer. 
The server has ip 192.168.6.5, another computer has ip 192.168.6.56(for example), and here is the question: how can I get an access from 192.168.6.56 to the webserver that works on 192.168.6.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a file in below location

"**tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco-global.properties**"

Which contains details regarding alfresco host and port configuration.

If changing that does not work.You will have firewall enabled in server.